# Subscription seems lost when error on Angular 11

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm not often working on Angular, so I don't really understand how it works.

I have a subscription like this :

```
    this.subscriptions.add(
      this.loadDataGrid.pipe(mergeMap((list: any) => this._ecSrvc.loadDataGrid(`api/getSomething?${this.sort ? `sort=${this.sort.field}:${this.sort.order}&` : ''}page=${this.page}&size=${this.size}`, list)))
        .subscribe((data: any) => {
          // does some stuff
        }, (error) => {
          // manage error
          return this.rowDataError = error ? error : true;
        })
    );
```

And I have this function triggered by sorting columns on PrimeNG Table :

```
  public loadData(event: LazyLoadEvent) {
    this.loading = true;
    if (this.size !== 0) {
      this.page = event.first / this.size;
    } else {
      this.page = 0;
    }
    if (event.sortField) {
      this.sort = {field: event.sortField, order: event.sortOrder === 1 ? 'desc' : 'asc'};
    }
    this.loadDataGrid.next(this.listFilter);
  }
```

This thing works.

I want to test if backend error are managed by angular. So I have a column that can be sorted (response status 200), and one that cannot (error status 422)

If I get the 422, then I try to sort with the good one (that should return a 200), the api call isn't triggered at all. The subscription seems lost. How should I manager the error in my subscription ?

I tried some code found in other questions but didn't work

Comment: This is how RxJS Observables work. When there is an unhandled error, the stream collapses and does not produce any more results. There are ways to continue the stream on errors, see the linked question.